# How do I screw my neighbor?

Tags: you-dont-know-jack

In the online multiplayer of the 2010 release of You Don't Know Jack, there is the ability to screw your neighbor, which forces them to have to answer the question right away.

I may have missed something in a tutorial and skipped over it, or they don't say, but I haven't seen any indication of how to actually execute this and choose who to screw.

Comment: I think Gaming.SE so far has the most interesting question titles lol

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [GameFly](http://www.gamefly.com/game/xbox-360/You-Don%29t-Know-Jack/145670/GameplayControls/), the left and right triggers will activate the screw.

Comment: @Blake: Giggity.